# Changing method of an abstract class in subclass

Tags: java, class, methods, subclass, abstract

I made a method in an abstract class namely the method String toString()

```
public String toString() {
    String res ="(" + Character.toString(propositieletter1) + " " + symboolconstante + " " + Character.toString(propositieletter2) + ")";
    return res;

}
```

this is a method of my abstract method, my subclasses need to use this method only change the "symboolconstante". I have no idea how I can do this without making the entire method again in my subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `symboolconstante` with a call to a `symboolconstante()` method. Each sub-class can override this method.

In the abstract class you can define it to be abstract :

```
protected abstract String symboolconstante();
```

In each sub-class you override it :

```
@Override
protected String symboolconstante()
{
    return "something";
}
```

And the abstract class's `toString()` method would call this method :

```
public String toString() {
    String res ="(" + Character.toString(propositieletter1) + " " + symboolconstante() + " " + Character.toString(propositieletter2) + ")";
    return res;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the abstract class define the field (private and final), then initialise the field in a contructor

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
  private final String symboolconstante;

  public AbstractClass (final String symbool) {
      this.symboolconstante = symbool;
  }
}
```

in the sub-class(s) amend the constructor to pass in the value to the abstract class

```
public class SubClass extends AbstractClass {
  public SubClass() {
    super("+");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the abstract toString method to take in a parameter

```
public String toString(final String symboolconstante) {
  String res ="(" + Character.toString(propositieletter1) + " " + symboolconstante + " " + Character.toString(propositieletter2) + ")";
  return res;

}
```

then in the sub class override toString passing in the parameter:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return super.toString("+");
}
```